# Shor's quantum 9 bit code

Tags: error-correction, quantum-computing

Regarding Shor's quantum 9 bit error correction code,
is the code corrects any error on any single qbit? Or is it corrects only a phase or a bit flip? How can i verify that?

Comment: For sure I'm too late, but you can play around with this code and check step by step what is being done in the Shor's 9-qubit algorithm for correcting quantum errors: https://github.com/sebastianvromero/qecc_shor9q . Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shor's 9-qubit code can correct against any single qubit error, as is explained e.g. in [these lecture notes](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/CPSC519/LectureNotes/16.pdf). You can verify this by e.g. checking the quantum error correction condition for the two codewords.